# Sitecore 9 forms - capture input from form then put that information to exm email template

Tags: sitecore-exm, sitecore9

How do you get the user input (e.g. First Name, Last Name etc...) from sitecore 9 forms then put that to exm email template before sending the email?

What i want to achieve is for example: I have a form that have first name, last name and position and comments field and i want that user input data (first and last name, position and comment) to be pass on the email template that on the EXM and send it as an email upon clicking the submit button in the form. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update the contact details, you can do that with a custom save action.

It is documented on the Sitecore doc website see:
[Walkthrough: Creating a custom submit action that updates contact details](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/digital_marketing/sitecore_forms/setting_up_and_configuring/walkthrough_creating_a_custom_submit_action_that_updates_contact_details)

This are the steps:

- Create a submit action class
- Create the SPEAK editor control
- Add a folder that contains parameters for the editor
- Create the client script for the editor
- Create a submit action item

The following blog explains [Sitecore Forms Send Email Campaign message](https://ggullentops.blogspot.com/2018/01/sitecore-forms-send-email-campaign.html) alternative you can also create an custom sent e-mail or if you need other examples of custom Forms extensions see [Sitecore-Forms-Extension-Pack](https://github.com/jbluemink/Sitecore-Forms-Extension-Pack)

Comment: Hi Jan, Thanks for the reply. Sorry but can't understand the part update the contact details? Why do i have to update the contact details? What i want to achieve is for example: I have a form that have first name, last name and position and comments field and i want that user input data (first and last name, position and comment) to be pass on the email template that on the EXM and send it as an email upon clicking the submit button in the form. Is that possible?

Comment: What you want is clear and and not a crazy wish, but outside of the data in the contact I do not know how to get it in EXM, but maybe an option to use a plain not EXM e-mail,? but this also required a custom save action. soon there is Sitecore 9.1 perhaps that gives more insight on how.